# Convert HTML to Rails legacy erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am using Rails 1.? and am not sure how to convert this HTML to Rails erb:

```
<a href=“menu”, id=“menu_type">menu</a>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this api](http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), link_to is a valid tag back in rails 1.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
<% link_to "Menu", { :action => "menu", :id => "menu_type" } %>
```